# Functions of finite sets with $k \vert |f^{-1} (k)|$

Tags: combinatorics, functions

How many functions $f: \{1, \cdots, n\} \to \{1, \cdots, n\}$ satisfy $k \vert |f^{-1} (k)|$ for all $1\le k \le n$?

I suspect this has something to do with the fact that for any partition of the set $\{1, \cdots, n\}$, the function sending $k$ to the size of the part of the partition containing $k$ satisfies the given property. However, I am unsure as to how to count these equivalence classes of partitions.

Comment: What does the notation k||f−1(k)| represent?

Comment: I mean $k$ must divide $|f^{-1} (k)|$ for all $1\le k\le n$.

Comment: So for $n=3$, would the functions sending $1,2,3$ to $1,1,1$ or to  $1,2,2$ or to  $2,1,2$ or to  $2,2,1$ or to $3,3,3$ all count, give an answer of $5$?

Comment: [OEIS A178682](http://oeis.org/A178682) gives Maple and Mathematica code and an exponential generating function but no explicit formula